# How to output first element in an struct array in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui, struct

If i have a struct like this:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var name: String
    let date: Date
    let id = UUID()
}
```

and for example i have 5 of those items in an array, something like this `@State private var items = [Item]()`

how can I display only the first item in that array in a view like this:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Text("First item:")
                 if items.isEmpty {
                               
                    Spacer()
                               
                    Text("No items, go find some!")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                               
                } else {
                    //I WANT TO DISPLAY THE FIRST ITEM HERE
                }

                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried typing `Text(items.first)` but i get an error "initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Item?' conform to 'StringProtocol'"

Is there a way that i can display the name and the date of a first Item in the items array?

I hope my question is clear enough.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for an `empty` array check if there is a `first` item

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            Text("First item:")
            if let firstItem = items.first {
                 Text(firstItem.name)  
                 Text(firstItem.date.formatted())         
            } else {
                 Spacer()
                           
                Text("No items, go find some!")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }

            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: then i get this error "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'"

Comment: The code does work if the `body` is inside a standard `View` struct plus the `items` array